# Find and search inside encrypted compressed files

Tags: search, archive

I want to get a list of all contents inside a (**ZipCrypto**) password protected zip archive inside the terminal.

Also, how can I filter/search specific file types using `grep` (Can I)?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt files, but still leave the file list unencrypted. If thats the case, save the following code, as `finda.sh`, or any other name as you like:

```
for file in *.*; do
    if ( 7z l -slt "$file"> /tmp/$file.log); then
       echo $file:; cat /tmp/$file.log | grep -iE 'Path*'> $file.log && cat $file.log
    fi
done
```

Save `funda.sh` In a directory were all of your archives are in, then execute it, and this is the output:

```
./finda.sh 
one.7z:
Path = one/abradabra.png
Path = one/birb.png
three.rar:
Path = three/blah.png
Path = three/qwa0g.jpg
two.zip:
Path = two/whut.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with encrypted compressed file.

But you can search for compressed files  with no password using `zgrep`

```
 zgrep 'word-to-search' /path/to/test.gz
```

`man zgrep`

> Zgrep  invokes grep on compressed or gzipped files.  All options
>   speci‐
>          fied are passed directly to grep.